# Combination of two Columns Laravel Validation Unique

Tags: laravel, validation, unique

I will go more in detail. First the table on which I wanna do the validation.

Tablename: groups_request; Columnname: idgroups_request (PK), iduser, idgroups, request_active, created_at, updated_at

At the moment a user (iduser) can make much requests per group (idgroups). The goal is, that the user can only make a request
to a group if the group hasn't already a request from this user.

Example: iduser = 1; idgroups = 100 -> User 1 is not allowed to make request to group 100!

For this I need a validation which make unique on two fields iduser and idgroups.

This is what I have worked out but it doesn't work. But it doesn't work.

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'Gruppe' => 'unique:groups_request,idgroups,' .Auth::id(). ',iduser'
        ]);
```

Comment: which two columns name? are they in the same table or different tables? give us more info and example to try helping.

Comment: Table: groups_request Fields:idgroups, iduser

Comment: what is **Gruppe** in the validation?
change it with required attribute validation which is **idgroups** in your example

Comment: In Gruppe is the required idgroups. Do I have to specify the two columns as unique field in the model?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, then, I think the best way is to make combination unique in the migration and wrap your code in the controller with `try` `catch` then return message if an exception happened. Something like following:

**Migration:**

```
$table->unique(['iduser', 'idgroups']);
```

**Controller:**

```
public function store()
{
    try {
        $model = Model::create(['iduser' => 1, 'idgroups' => 1]);
    } catch (\Exception $exception){
        // If already there is record with **iduser = 1** and **idgroups = 1** the exception will be thrown and your code here will be executed
    }
}
```